# Yoash what does it mean

Tags: names, translation, melachim-kings-book-of

I’ve a short question about the biblical name Yoash (יאש or יואש or יהואש, see e.g. [מלכים ב:י"ב:ב](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%91_%D7%99%D7%91_%D7%91)), online I came across the meaning of: ‘HaShem has given’ or ‘Given by HaShem’, many times. But how can the word אש, which means fire, mean ‘given’?

Comment: It seems to me the name means "fire of G-d."

Comment: Maybe it’s a combination of the Tetragrammaton (the leading yud) and אש as in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theophory_in_the_Bible

Comment: Why would it not mean כִּי יְהוָה אֱלֹהֶיךָ אֵשׁ אֹכְלָה הוּא?

Comment: The "אש" part is spelled with a kamatz: אָשׁ. Hence, not necessarily the same word as fire, which is spelled with a tzereh: אֵשׁ.

Answer (score 3):

R. [Eleazar of Worms](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleazar_of_Worms) (Rimze Haftarot, [Parshat Shekalim, p. 4b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46779&st=&pgnum=9&hilite=)) asserted that the etymology of the name is ‘despair’, for the people had despaired of Davidic reign (cited by Prof. Louis Ginzberg, Legends of the Jews vol. 6 p. 354).

R. Eleazar’s connotation may have been predicated on the Bavli (BB [91b](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.91b.9?with=all&lang=bi)).